# How to specify maximum condition for datetime-local type input field in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, user-interface, material-ui, frontend

I have to get the start date-time and the end date-time from the user. But the end date-time should not be more than 12 hours from the start date-time. I want to restrict the end input field.

`<TextField label="start time" type="datetime-local" required />`

`<TextField label="end time" type="datetime-local" required />`

Comment: Why MUI `<TextField>` and not a `<DateTimePicker>`? That would solve your problem. https://mui.com/x/react-date-pickers/date-time-picker/#date-and-time-validation